# Playing around with jQuery objects and variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('div#Settings ul li').click(function () {
        var url, template;
        var self = $(this);
        if (!$(self).hasClass('selected')) {
            var ContextMenu = CreateContext($(self));
            var id = $(self).attr('id');
```

etc...

```
function CreateContext(item) {
        var ContextMenu = $('div#ContextMenu');
        if (!$(ContextMenu).length) {
            $('<div id="ContextMenu"></div>').appendTo('body');
            CreateContext(item);
        }
        $(ContextMenu).slideUp(150, 'swing', function () {
            $(ContextMenu).insertAfter(item);
        });
        $(item).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        return $(ContextMenu);
    }
```

On the first call to `CreateContext(item)` I cannot use the variable `ContextMenu` later in the `.click` code. However, if CreateContext is called twice, everything works fine. I am getting an undefined variable when i `console.log(ContextMenu)` the first time. The second time it gets the object correctly. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `div#ContextMenu` doesn't exist the first time you call CreateContext.  In fact your function detects that condition and then creates it.  But, after creating it, you don't populate the value of `ContextMenu` inside your function so the rest of the function doesn't work properly.

Here's what I would suggest:

```
function CreateContext(item) {
    var ContextMenu = $('#ContextMenu');
    if (!ContextMenu.length) {
        ContextMenu = $('<div id="ContextMenu"></div>');
        ContextMenu.appendTo('body');
    }
    ContextMenu.slideUp(150, 'swing', function () {
        ContextMenu.insertAfter(item);
    });
    $(item).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    return ContextMenu;
}
```

Note, once `ContextMenu` is a jQuery object, you don't have to surround it with `$()` after that as it's already a jQuery object.

Comment: @user1027620 - You are creating and appending it, but you weren't setting the value of the local variable `ContextMenu` after creating it so the rest of the code couldn't use the one you just created.  Note how my suggested code sets the value of `ContextMenu` when creating it.

Comment: @user1027620 - you'll have to show me what code you're using.  I've edited mine a few times so I'm not sure which one you grabbed.

Comment: @user1027620 - you are not supposed to put the solution in your question.  You are supposed to check the checkmark by the answer that offers you the best solution to indicate that that answer is the best solution and to give the answerer credit for offering it.

Comment: Yeah I can't check it yet. Says I can in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the jQuery indicator out of your function. Since you've declared the variable as a jQuery object, I don't believe you need to identify it as a jQuery object AGAIN in your  function.